# Incorrect magic error when connecting to local naoqi via javascript using robotutils lib

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I want to test my Javascript Application for Pepper locally.

Therefore I would like to connect my Javascript Application to a local naoqi.

After starting the naoqi-bin.exe locally I run my webpage with the robot argument `index.html?robot=127.0.0.1:9559`

But I keep on getting the following message from naoqi-bin.exe (Version 2.5.10.7):

```
[W] 1557132108.799995 15136 qimessaging.transportsocket: Incorrect magic from 127.0.0.1, disconnecting (expected 1118690882, got 542393671).
[V] 1557143050.368227 15380 qimessaging.transportsocket: Socket error: Protocol error
```

What does this message mean?

The Browser Console also shows failing to load `http://127.0.0.1:9559/libs/qimessaging/2/qimessaging.js`

Also opening `http://127.0.0.1:9559/libs/qimessaging/2/qimessaging.js` directly as URL reproduces the Error.

Here is a simple HTML example that also reproduces the problem:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="js/robotutils.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      RobotUtils.onService(function (ALDialog) {
        console.log("Connected the service.")
    }, function() {
        console.log("Failed to get the service.")
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Folder Structure:

- app/html/index.html
- app/html/js/robotutils.js (version 0.3)

Output from naoqi-bin.exe:

```
[I] 1557131965.486673 9424 qimessaging.servicedirectory: ServiceDirectory listener created on tcp://127.0.0.1:9559
[I] 1557131965.660131 9424 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://127.0.0.1:9559
[I] 1557131965.665147 9424 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ServiceDirectory" (#1)
[I] 1557131965.676707 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "LogManager" (#2)
[I] 1557131965.692749 15136 packagemanager: Installing system packages
[I] 1557131965.692749 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "PackageManager" (#3)
[I] 1557131965.694756 15136 packagemanager: Finished installing system packages
[I] 1557131965.704817 9424 core.alservicemanager: autostart service : Naoqi from system package
[I] 1557131965.706289 9424 core.alservicemanager: Starting service system.Naoqi
[I] 1557131965.706289 9424 core.alservicemanager: autostart service : MdnsRegistrarService from system package
[I] 1557131965.707293 9424 core.alservicemanager: Starting service system.MdnsRegistrarService
[I] 1557131965.708298 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALServiceManager" (#4)
[I] 1557131965.713309 15096 core.processmanager.qt: Starting C:\Program Files (x86)\Softbank Robotics\Choregraphe Suite 2.5\bin\naoqi-service.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Softbank Robotics\Choregraphe Suite 2.5\share\naoqi\apps\naoqi
[I] 1557131965.723545 15096 core.processmanager.qt: Starting C:\Program Files (x86)\Softbank Robotics\Choregraphe Suite 2.5\bin\qilaunch.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Softbank Robotics\Choregraphe Suite 2.5\share\naoqi\apps\naoqi
[I] 1557131965.734575 15096 core.processmanager.qt: system.Naoqi has started
[I] 1557131965.735578 15096 core.processmanager.qt: system.MdnsRegistrarService has started
[I] 1557131966.202012 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALFileManager" (#5)
[I] 1557131966.213044 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALMemory" (#6)
[I] 1557131966.216052 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALLogger" (#7)
[I] 1557131966.218056 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALPreferences" (#8)
[I] 1557131966.223068 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALLauncher" (#9)
[I] 1557131966.231094 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALDebug" (#10)
[I] 1557131966.239112 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALPreferenceManager" (#11)
[I] 1557131966.244126 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALNotificationManager" (#12)
[I] 1557131966.259164 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALResourceManager" (#14)
[I] 1557131966.278215 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALRobotModel" (#15)
[I] 1557131966.295260 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALSonar" (#16)
[I] 1557131966.310300 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALFsr" (#17)
[I] 1557131966.325340 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALSensors" (#18)
[I] 1557131966.344390 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALBodyTemperature" (#19)
[I] 1557131966.590435 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALMotion" (#20)
[I] 1557131966.619512 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALTouch" (#21)
[I] 1557131966.703737 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALRobotPosture" (#22)
[I] 1557131966.722786 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALMotionRecorder" (#23)
[I] 1557131966.789965 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALLeds" (#24)
[I] 1557131966.819042 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALWorldRepresentation" (#25)
[I] 1557131966.868172 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALKnowledgeManager" (#26)
[I] 1557131966.870177 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALKnowledge" (#27)
[I] 1557131966.915305 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALAudioPlayer" (#28)
[I] 1557131966.927163 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALTextToSpeech" (#29)
[I] 1557131966.958036 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALBattery" (#30)
[I] 1557131966.983025 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALFrameManager" (#31)
[I] 1557131966.990053 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALPythonBridge" (#32)
[I] 1557131967.215841 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALVideoDevice" (#33)
[I] 1557131967.226812 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALRedBallDetection" (#34)
[I] 1557131967.307025 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALVisionRecognition" (#35)
[I] 1557131967.328664 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALBehaviorManager" (#36)
[I] 1557131967.364690 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALAnimationPlayer" (#38)
[I] 1557131967.376966 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALSpeakingMovement" (#39)
[I] 1557131967.401665 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALAnimatedSpeech" (#40)
[I] 1557131967.415486 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALColorBlobDetection" (#41)
[I] 1557131967.430525 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALVisualSpaceHistory" (#42)
[I] 1557131967.530201 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALTracker" (#58)
[I] 1557131967.618950 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALModularity" (#59)
[I] 1557131967.681688 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALNavigation" (#60)
[I] 1557131967.700078 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALMovementDetection" (#61)
[I] 1557131967.723630 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALSegmentation3D" (#62)
[I] 1557131967.758703 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALPeoplePerception" (#64)
[I] 1557131967.800768 15228 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALSittingPeopleDetection" (#65)
[I] 1557131967.820436 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALEngagementZones" (#66)
[I] 1557131967.843412 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALGazeAnalysis" (#67)
[I] 1557131967.866404 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALWavingDetection" (#68)
[I] 1557131967.886654 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALCloseObjectDetection" (#69)
[I] 1557131967.958956 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALVisualCompass" (#72)
[I] 1557131968.001494 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALLocalization" (#73)
[I] 1557131968.010783 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALPanoramaCompass" (#74)
[I] 1557131968.013791 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALUserInfo" (#75)
[I] 1557131968.095568 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALUserSession" (#76)
[I] 1557131968.112603 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALThinkingExpression" (#78)
[I] 1557131968.147911 15140 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALBasicAwareness" (#79)
[I] 1557131968.187510 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALBackgroundMovement" (#80)
[I] 1557131968.198511 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALListeningMovement" (#81)
[I] 1557131968.220421 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALExpressionWatcher" (#83)
[I] 1557131968.347999 15136 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALAutonomousLife" (#95)
[I] 1557131968.481927 15132 qimessaging.servicedirectory: Registered Service "ALDialog" (#96)
```

## Edit:

The Error Messages in Naoqi only appears, when the URL Parameter

```
?robot=127.0.0.1:9559
```

contains the port.

Without 9559 the message does not appear anymore.

Now it is possible to connect to a real robot.
But connecting to a virtual robot still fails.

And the Browser Console still shows an Error loading a resource http://127.0.0.1/libs/qimessaging/2/qimessaging.js

So it seems as the vurtial robot does not serve this file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to virtual Robot via QiMessaging JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037157/connect-to-virtual-robot-via-qimessaging-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed, the connection to a virtual robot cannot work, since qimessaging javascript doesn't directly connect to NAOqi.