# Connect to virtual Robot via QiMessaging JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nao-robot, pepper

I would like to test my Javascript application locally.

Therefore i would like to establish a connection between my JavaScript Application with QiMessaging to a virtual robot.

**Has anybody done this before?**

**Is this even possible?**

As virtual robot I tried naoqi-bin.exe and opennao vm on my windows 10 system.

It works fine with a real Robot (Pepper) by connecting to a virtual robot didnt work.

Here are my attempts:

---

### qimessaging 1.0:

#### code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>    
<body>
<script src="libs/qimessaging/1.0/qimessaging.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var robot_address = '127.0.0.1'    

  var session = new QiSession(robot_address);
    session.socket().on('connect', function () {
  console.log('QiSession connected!');
  // now you can start using your QiSession
}).on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('QiSession disconnected!');
});        
</script>
</body>    
</html>
```

#### result:

Broweser Console shows:

> 404 Not Found
>   http://127.0.0.1/libs/qimessaging/1.0/socket.io/1/?t=1557305266224
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1/libs/qimessaging/1.0/socket.io/1/?t=1557305266224 Reson: Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

---

### qimessaging 2.0:

#### code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>    
<body>
<script src="libs/qi/2/qi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var robot_address = '127.0.0.1'

    QiSession(function (session) {
      console.log("connected!");
      // you can now use your QiSession
    }, function () {
      console.log("disconnected");
    },
      robot_address);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### result:

same as with qimessaging 1.0

---

### robotutils:

#### code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>    
<body>
  <script src="js/robotutils.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    RobotUtils.robotIp = "127.0.0.1"

    RobotUtils.onService(function (ALDialog) {
      console.log("Connected the service.")         
    }, function () {
      console.log("Failed to get the service.")
    })
  </script>
</body>   
</html>
```

#### result:

> GET http://127.0.0.1/libs/qimessaging/2/qimessaging.js 404 Not Found
>
> The script from “http://127.0.0.1/libs/qimessaging/2/qimessaging.js”
>   was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid
>   JavaScript MIME type.
>
> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “http://127.0.0.1/libs/qimessaging/2/qimessaging.js”.

---

So my interpretationis that the virtual robot does not serve the required files or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer in a the [aldebaran forum](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/ja/node/9522)

> [...]
>
> Sorry, but qimessaging javascript won't work with a virtual
> robot, only with a real robot (on a real robot there's a server
> listening to a certain port for qimessaging js communication, there's
> no such server running for a virtual robot).
>
> [...]